# Regex - match only first occurence in line and ignore every second

Tags: regex

I have a line from a text file that I want to only match the first occurrence of a number and ignore the second.
The String looks like this:

```
Dauerstufe              1 a             1 a             2 a             2 a             3 a             3 a             5 a             5 a            10 a            10 a            20 a            20 a            30 a            30 a            50 a            50 a           100 a           100 a
```

So I only want to match: `1 2 3 5 10 20 30 50 100` or any other number that a user might want to enter.
Matching only numbers is pretty easy to do with `[0-9]+`.
But how do I get it to only match the first one?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: I forgot to say that the regex is to be used in vba.

Comment: use programming language

Comment: You can always remove duplicates after you got the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to use a hash table or associative array.

Use your matched number as the key.

PHP example below:

```
$myarray[$x] = "";
```

Later on, just loop the keys for the array. Since it will just override if the key exists, you won't have to worry about removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

use this `(.*?)(?'first'\d{1,3})(.+?)(\k{first})( a)`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/FxJJT5/2)

Comment: is there any way to make this work in vba? (See edited original question) and only match the numbers - not everything around it?

Answer (score 0):

To get the values you are looking for, you might also select the last occurrences using a negative lookahead.

[`\b(\d+)\b(?!.*\1\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/7Q2dUl/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/[0-9]+/` regexp and set `Global` flag on the RegExp object.

```
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "[0-9]+"
```

See details on: [How to Use the VBScript RegExp Object](https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)